# Telling VX-Tasking that "bool" in a boolean?

Tags: c, eclipse, misra

I'm using the Tasking VX toolset (built on Eclipse) and have a fairly basic but fundamental problem that I can't get around... I've RTFMed and am still totally none the wiser.

Imagine the simple snippet of code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool myFlag = false;
```

If I enable MISRA-C checking, I get the following:

```
MISRA-C rule 10.1 violation: [R] restrict the use of implicit conversions for integer types
```

Eclipse is set up as a C99 implementation, and as per the [standard library definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), `stdbool.h` is defined as:

```
#define bool  _Bool
#define true  1
#define false 0
```

I'm assuming that this error is because `#define false 0` and the tool is implicitly converting to bool?

Note: if I cast the assignment, then the error is removed:

```
 bool myFlag = (bool)false;
```

But (IMHO) that is masking the problem, not addressing it, and I really do not want to cast every assignment.

Tools such as LINT allow you to specify the bool type to stop these sort of false positives... I need the equivalent for Eclipse/Tasking

---

So my question is this:

**I suspect that somewhere there is a tool option to tell TASKING that `bool` is the boolean type, and therefore `false` and `true` are OK to be used?**

Is there?

{Please no discussions [on this thread] about the merits (or otherwise) of MISRA}

Comment: Do you get the warning with `bool myFlag = (bool) false;`?

Comment: No... hence my assumption.  But I really do not want to clutter every bool set or test with a cast.

Comment: The best idea might be to `#define TRUE 1u` etc, but then the code needs to be rewritten to use the upper case version everywhere. The root of the problem is that you are using C99, and MISRA-C:2004 does not allow nor support C99.

Comment: @lundin - in a way you are correct, but (and I'll have to check) even in MISRA-C:2012 this may be an issue (_BOOL being set to an unsigned int) because of the borked way that stdbool.h defines the bool type...

Comment: @Andrew If the final version of MISRA-C:2012 will be anything like the draft, then they will change their definition of types in expressions. Instead of the old term "underlying type", they plan to introduce something called "essential type". Boolean expressions will have "essential boolean" type, and the static analyser must treat them correctly. MISRA even states that "bool enums" in C90 should be treated as essential boolean. But of course, this is just a draft for now. It looks MISRA-C:2012 will be handle implicit type conversions far better and smoother than 2004 anyhow.

Comment: @Lundin - now I've checked my Latest Draft, it looks like this one will sort itself. And yes, this area is pretty much unchanged from the Review Draft. {just for the record, I'm on the committee :-)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MISRA rule 10.1 says

> (Rule 10.1) The value of an expression of integer type shall not be implicitly converting to a different underlying type if:
>
> a) it is not a conversion to a wider integer type of the same signedness, or
>
> b) the expression is complex, or
>
> c) the expression is not constant and is a function argument, or
>
> d) the expression is not constant and is a return expression

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool myFlag = false;
```

is the same as:

```
_Bool myFlag = 0;
```

`0` is of type `int` which is a signed integer type but `_Bool` is an unsigned integer type.
You are implicitly converting a value of a signed type to a value of an unsigned type and so
you are violating `a)` in MISRA rule 10.1.

Note that if you are using MISRA-C:2004 (I don't think MISRA-C:2012 has been released), at the time of the publication only C90 was considered and `_Bool` is a C99 addition. As I wrote in the comments you can get rid of the warning using a cast like this:

```
bool myFlag = (bool) false;
```

This is the beauty of MISRA.

Comment: No, MISRA-C:2012 has not been released yet (imminently...)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way around it, but you could define bool yourself like that:

```
typedef enum _bool { false = 0, true = 1 } bool;
bool x = false;
```

This should pass the strict checks.

Comment: That is, of course, what the C Language **should** have done!

Comment: You then also have to remove the `stdbool.h` header and you will not have the same behavior as `_Bool` has (for example for usual arithmetic conversions).

Comment: enum has plenty of signedness problems by its own, they are so weird that enum variables and enum constants don't necessarily have the same signedness and width. Instead, use #defines and write `0u`, `1u` instead.

Comment: Calling that enumerated type `bool` will cause confusion because you now have two types named `bool` with subtly different behaviour and (on many systems) different size (commonly, `sizeof(_Bool)` is 1 and `sizeof(enum _bool)` is 4).

Answer (score 0):

You can `#undef` `true` and `false` after `#include <stdbool.h>` and define them to new values that make the MISRA stuff happy.

This practice is permitted by C99 and C11 as an obsolescent feature.

Comment: This is not a good idea, since #undef is banned by MISRA-C 19.6 and redefining items from the standard library is banned by 20.1.